# Core Animation and Transformation like zoomRectToVisible

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, translation, transformation

I'm trying to get an effect like the `zoomRectToVisible`-method of UIScrollview.
But my method should be able to center the particular rect in the layer while zooming and it should be able to re-adjust after the device orientation changed.

I'm trying to write a software like the marvel-comic app and need a view that presents each panel in a page.

For my implementation I'm using CALayer and Core Animation to get the desired effect with CATransform3D-transformations. My problem is, I'm not able to get the zoomed rect/panel centered.

the structure of my implementation looks like this: I have a subclass of UIScrollview with a UIView added as subview. The UIView contains the image/page in it's CALayer.contents and I use core animations to get the zooming and centering effect. The zoom effect on each panel works correcty but the centering is off. I'm not able to compute the correct translate-transformation for centering.

My code for the implementation of the effect is like this:

```
- (void) zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.bounds.size;

    // get the current panel boundingbox
    CGRect panelboundingBox = CGPathGetBoundingBox([comicPage panelAtIndex:currentPanel]);

    // compute zoomfactor depending on the longer dimension of the panelboundingBox size
    CGFloat zoomFactor = (panelboundingBox.size.height > panelboundingBox.size.width) ? scrollViewSize.height/panelboundingBox.size.height : scrollViewSize.width/panelboundingBox.size.width;

    CGFloat translateX = scrollViewSize.width/2 - (panelboundingBox.origin.x/2 + panelboundingBox.size.width/2);
    CGFloat translateY = scrollViewSize.height/2 - (panelboundingBox.size.height/2 - panelboundingBox.origin.y);

    // move anchorPoint to panelboundingBox center
    CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(1/contentViewLayer.bounds.size.width * (panelboundingBox.origin.x + panelboundingBox.size.width/2), 1/contentViewLayer.bounds.size.height * (contentViewLayer.bounds.size.height - (panelboundingBox.origin.y + panelboundingBox.size.height/2)));


    // create the nessesary transformations
    CATransform3D translateMatrix = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(translateX, -translateY, 1);
    CATransform3D scaleMatrix = CATransform3DMakeScale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, 1);

    // create respective core animation for transformation
    CABasicAnimation *zoomAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    zoomAnimation.fromValue =  (id) [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:contentViewLayer.transform];
    zoomAnimation.toValue = (id) [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DConcat(scaleMatrix, translateMatrix)];
    zoomAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    zoomAnimation.duration = duration;

    // create respective core animation for anchorpoint movement
    CABasicAnimation *anchorAnimatione = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"anchorPoint"];
    anchorAnimatione.fromValue = (id)[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:contentViewLayer.anchorPoint];
    anchorAnimatione.toValue = (id) [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:anchor];
    anchorAnimatione.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    anchorAnimatione.duration = duration;

    // put them into an animation group
    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:zoomAnimation, anchorAnimatione, nil] ;

    /////////////

    NSLog(@"scrollViewBounds (w = %f, h = %f)", self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"panelBounds (x = %f, y = %f, w = %f, h = %f)", panelboundingBox.origin.x, panelboundingBox.origin.y, panelboundingBox.size.width, panelboundingBox.size.height);
    NSLog(@"zoomfactor: %f", zoomFactor);
    NSLog(@"translateX: %f, translateY: %f", translateX, translateY);
    NSLog(@"anchorPoint (x = %f, y = %f)", anchor.x, anchor.y);

    /////////////

    // add animation group to layer 
    [contentViewLayer addAnimation:group forKey:@"zoomAnimation"];

    // trigger respective animations
    contentViewLayer.anchorPoint = anchor;
    contentViewLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(scaleMatrix, translateMatrix);
}
```

So the view requires the following points:

1. it should be able to zoom and center a rect/panel of the layer/view depending on the current device orientation. (zoomRectToVisible of UIScrollview does not center the rect)
2. if nessesary (either device orientation changed or panel requires rotation) the zoomed panel/rect should be able to rotate
3. the duration of the animation is depending on user preference. (I don't know whether I can change the default animation duration of zoomRectToVisible of UIScrollView ?)

Those points are the reason why I overwrite the zoomRectToVisible-method of UIScrollView.

So I have to know how I can correctly compute the translation parameters for the transformation.

I hope someone can guide me to get the correct parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Just skimmed over your code and this line is probably not being calculated as you think:

```
CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(1/contentViewLayer.bounds.size.width * (panelboundingBox.origin.x + panelboundingBox.size.width/2), 1/contentViewLayer.bounds.size.height * (contentViewLayer.bounds.size.height - (panelboundingBox.origin.y + panelboundingBox.size.height/2)));
```

You're likely to get 0 because of the 1/ at the start. C will do your multiplication before this division, resulting in values <1 - probably not what you're after. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages)

You might find it more useful to breakdown your calculation so you know it's working in the right order (just use some temporary variables) - believe me it will help enormously in making your code easier to read (and debug) later. Or you could just use more brackets...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both `*` and `/` have the same operator precedence (see your link). This actually means they will be (logically) executed from left to right.